# HTML in iCal using iCal4j

Tags: java, outlook, outlook-2007, icalendar, vcalendar

Is there a possibility to add html to a description from a vevent.

I generate a `VCALENDAR` with a `VEVENT` with a description. I use [Ical4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) to sent the email with `ICS`

This is what I try to do:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//----//Calendar 1.0//ES
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20101202T145512Z
UID:20101202T145513Z-project@myPc
DESCRIPTION:ALTREP="CID:content-id-here":BlaBla
LOCATION:Room 2
SUMMARY:Confirmation
DTSTART:20110115T180000
DTEND:20110115T184500
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:foo@bar.com
ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=EyeContact:mailto:foo@bar.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Content-Type:text/html
Content-Id:content-id-here

   <html>
     <head>
      <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <p>
         <b>Example</b>
       </p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Now it simply show the HTML code.

The above calendar I put in a MultiPart

```
message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
message.addHeaderLine("component=vevent");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(app.getPanelist().getEmail()));
message.setSubject(subject);
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart iCalAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
iCalAttachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(invite), "text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=\"UTF-8\"")));
mp.addBodyPart(iCalAttachment);
message.setContent(mp);
```

Do I miss a part or is impossible?

**EDIT - What I try to do with iCal4j (using Altrep)**

```
ParameterList params = new ParameterList();     
URI uri = new URI("CID:content-id-here");
params.add(new AltRep(uri));
vEvent.getProperties().add(new Description(params,_content));
```

But with the code from above I'am stuck. Somebody a idea to use HTML in combination with iCall4j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in this blogspot:

http://valermicle.blogspot.com/2009/02/i-was-searching-for-documentations-on.html

Using a MultiPart on the correct manner solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the iCalendar specifications, it looks like you need an "Alternate Text Representation" See [RFC 5545 Section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.1)

> Example:
>
> ```
>    DESCRIPTION;ALTREP="CID:part3.msg.970415T083000@example.com":
>     Project XYZ Review Meeting will include the following agenda
>      items: (a) Market Overview\, (b) Finances\, (c) Project Man
>     agement
> ```
>
> The "ALTREP" property parameter value might point to a "text/html"
> content portion.
>
> ```
>    Content-Type:text/html
>    Content-Id:<part3.msg.970415T083000@example.com>
>
>    <html>
>      <head>
>       <title></title>
>      </head>
>      <body>
>        <p>
>          <b>Project XYZ Review Meeting</b> will include
>          the following agenda items:
>          <ol>
>            <li>Market Overview</li>
>            <li>Finances</li>
>            <li>Project Management</li>
>          </ol>
>        </p>
>      </body>
>    </html>
> ```

Comment: mm I need to look into this, but is seems that is must reference to a other content part of your email...

I get an error like:

'.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: <p>'...

Comment: after escaping: same error: .URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: &lt;p&gt;

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? What are you setting the URI to?